# Scala - inferred as wrong type, leading to type mismatch?

Tags: scala, inheritance, types

In Scala 2.11.5, compiling this

```
object Tryout {
  trait A {
    def method(a: Int): Boolean
  }

  abstract class B extends A {
    def method(a: Int) = ???
  }

  new B {
    override def method(a: Int) = true  // type mismatch here
  }
}
```

yields a "type mismatch: found Boolean, required Nothing" at the "true". If I replace the `???` with true or false, it compiles. It also compiles if I specify the result type of "method" in the abstract class.

This is not a big issue. However I'm curious whether anybody can explain why `???` is not inferred correctly as Boolean?

Comment: change it to `def method(a: Int): Boolean = ???` in abstract class B.

Comment: This is actually a known bug. If I could find the ticket I'd link it. It is slated to be fixed in 2.12 I believe.

Comment: @wheaties Are you sure that's a bug? It seems consistent to me that the compiler would infer the most specific type (Nothing is a subtype of Boolean).

Comment: Why do you think its a bug... ? Looks consistent...

Comment: Because you're overriding the type as given in the interface

Comment: @m-z thanks for reminding me to check. I think the first answer fully addresses the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala allows you to make the return type of an inherited method more restrictive in a sub-class.

```
abstract class A {
    def foo: Any
}

abstract class B {
    def foo: Int
}

new B {
    def foo = 1
}
```

So when you declare `def method(a: Int) = ???` in `B`, `???` is inferred as `Nothing`, because the scala compiler doesn't know if you want `Boolean` or `Nothing`. This is one of the reasons why it is always a good idea to explicitly declare return types.

Answer (score 4):

Return type of `def method(a: Int) = ???` is actually `Nothing`.

```
scala> def method(a: Int) = ???
method: (a: Int)Nothing
```

Now, `method` in class `B` is overriding the `method` from the parent trait. You should define your claas B like this,

```
abstract class B extends A {
  // def method is provided by trait A
}
```

or

```
abstract class B extends A {
  // def method with full signature
  override def method(a: Int): Boolean = ???
}
```